# Cannot get unattended-upgrades to work

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS and I am currently trying to get unattended-upgrades to work. So far I followed this documentation: [12.04-serverguide-automatic-updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html)

1. I installed the package: `apt-get install unattended-upgrades`
2. I edited the configuration file with `vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`
3. After that I tried to edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`, but that file was missing.

   - Does one have to create it manually?

Finally, I wondered how starts triggering unattended-upgrades and in which intervals? The file `/etc/cron.daily/apt` is missing on my system as well.

- Should it be there?

Seems to be a common problem: [unattended-upgrades not running, /etc/cron.daily/apt missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263692/unattended-upgrades-not-running-etc-cron-daily-apt-missing)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the missing file `/etc/cron.daily/apt`:
The file is part of the apt package.
Thus, I downloaded the package via `apt-get download apt`, extracted it and manually copied the file named apt to the said location.

I do not know why this file has not been copied during a "normal" `apt-get install apt`; I even tried an `apt-get install --reinstall apt` without success.

Regarding the second missing file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`:
This one I created manually (which seems to be "works as designed") and edited it according to the documentation part of the `/etc/cron.daily/apt` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a file called 10periodic, which I haven't created myself; it is identical to the on in the linked question. I also have a file /etc/cron.daily/apt which is much longer, but looks much the same as the one in the link. Either copy that one over to your installation, or try installing `cron-apt`.

Comment: I have tried installing cron-apt. The installation runs through, but I am still missing the files mentioned. Any idea why they are missing? When googling around it turns out that there are some other users with the same issue - many of their posts are even from 2013, but there are no real good answers. Hasn't this been reported as issue to the package maintainers? I am new to Ubuntu and such issues don't let me feel very confident...